# Strange bug with resizing of UI elements in xCode 5? Video is attached

Tags: ios, user-interface, resize, interface-builder, xcode5

[link to a video with bug](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sT9Guhn8rfs&feature=youtu.be)

I simply created a project in xCode. Then I added any UI element to a view. Then I tried to resize this item to left and to right. No code, Interface Builder was used only.

I have checked with some types of projects for iOS and with UILabel and UIButton. The result is the same: when I try to resize the item from the left then it moves the parent view/viewcontroller instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Uncheck "**Siblings and Ancestors**" under **Resizing Behavior** in Xcode 5 Storyboard.

Voila! As such, resizing your UI elements will not cause your view controllers to move.

Comment: thanks, was really annoying buliding interface with that checked

Comment: @Gargo The goal of this feature, explained in jaysoncopes's answer right below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165180/strange-bug-with-resizing-of-ui-elements-in-xcode-5-video-is-attached/27509239#27509239

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncheck the "Siblings and Ancestors" in your .xib/.storyboard file. See below screenshot of how to toggle this behavior on and off:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As has been said before, you must uncheck the "Siblings and Ancestors" option under **Resizing Behavior** in the Xcode 5 Storyboard.

The specific purpose of this feature is to be able to resize large groups of objects all at once. For instance, lets say that you have a Table View and you resize one of the cells. In this case, it would seem petty, since you would just have to resize the Table View Controller, but it becomes extremely handy once you have layered objects such as that.

Sorry for the somewhat duplicate answer, but you did ask for an explanation of why a feature like that would be added.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally I have found out that another computer with the same version of xCode works with the same copy of project normally.

I didn't know how to solve this problem without uninstalling of xCode.

So I uninstalled it using AppCleaner and installed it again.